# MySQL combine 2 tables into 1

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables (Pickup and Dropoff) entries are
made frequently in both. I have a query to delete 
and make the Combo table matching the psernum to the dsernum
upon request. As the database grows,
the query to delete and make the combo table is
getting slow. Is there a better way to keep the combo table
up to date with the Pickup and Dropoff tables other then a query
to delete and rebuild?

```
Table: Pickup
=======================
id | psernum  | pname  |
=======================
1  | 0001  | Fred      |
2  | 0002  | Bill      |
3  | 0003  | Chuck     |
4  | 0004  | Tom       |
=======================

Table: Dropoff
========================
id | dsernum  | dname  |
========================
22| 0001 | Carl        |
23| 0002 | Joe         |      
24| 0003 | Mike        |
========================

Table: Combo
==============================================
 id |psernum  | pname    | dsernum  | dname  |
==============================================
 1  |0001       | Fred   | 0001     | Carl   |
 2  |0002       | Bill   | 0002     | Joe    |
 3  |0003       | Chuck  | 0003     | Mike   |
 4  |0004       | Tom    |NULL      | NULL   |
=============================================
```

Comment: You can create a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks  Giorgos Betsos  not much faster in cusory test